# How to edit fishshell startup script

Tags: fish

I am on arch linux and have installed the fish shell together with oh-my-fish

Can someone tell me which file i edit to add my custom shell startup commands

im zsh it was the ~.zshrc what is it in fish shell ?

i have a problem, if i put my stuff in bashrc it is not loaded by fish, if i enter shell comands in the fish file `~/.config/fish/config.fish` it throws errors

Comment: Show your config.fish and show the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fish#Configuration) ?

```
~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Comment: can i treat that as .zshrc and put shell commands direct in there?

Comment: I use bash, but according to wiki - yes.

Comment: i have a problem, if i put my stuff in bashrc it is not loaded by fish, if i enter shell comands in the fish file it throws errors

Comment: Bash and Fish are different shells, Fish doesn't read bashrc.  If you enter commands in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` they throw errors? What error exactly, note that config.fish should only have fish command, not bash or other shells

Comment: i can make my own custom.sh file, how do i get fish to load that on startup

Comment: put context of custom.sh into config.fish